# Obtener resultado query en laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo la siguiente consulta que se realiza desde el Controller en Laravel

```
$IdUnidadPadre2Nivel = \DB::select('select padre from unidades where id = ?', [$unidadAsociadaEmerg])[0];
```

Esto me trae un "objeto", y necesito obtener el valor (en este caso el valor de la variable padre) de ese objeto, pero al hacer:

```
print_r("$IdUnidadPadre2Nivel : ". $IdUnidadPadre2Nivel);
```

Me arroja este error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.

Como puedo obtener el valor retornado por el query?
Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Al ser un objeto que buscas imprimir deberas convertirlo a json con `json_encode` o bien, si conoces la propiedad del objeto, debes apuntar hacia él

```
print_r($IdUnidadPadre2Nivel->propiedad);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono de la siguiente forma  print_r(json_decode(IdUnidadPadre2Nivel->padre));